# Linear Equations - What's wrong with my solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

This is the math problem: -(b-1) = 1(1-4) - 4(b+8)
This is what I came up with:

```
-b + 1 = 1 - 4 - 4b - 32
-b + 33 = 1 - 4 - 4b
-5b + 33 = 1 - 4
-5b = -3 - 33 
-5b = -36
b = -36/-5
```

and It's apparently wrong for some reason. I'm supposed to get b = -12.
Where am I doing it wrong? 
Also does the order of operations matter here?

Comment: From line 2 to line 3 you are adding $4b$ to both sides, but you subtracted it from the left side, which should read "$3b+33$".

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  To find where you are doing it wrong, plug $b=-12$ in to each line and see if it's true

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be this:

$-b + 1 = 1 - 4 - 46 - 32$

$-b + 33 = 1 - 4 - 4b$

$\color{red}3b + 33 = 1 - 4$

$3b = -3 - 33 $

$3b = -36$

$b = -12$

Comment: why 3b and not 4b?

Comment: we added $4b$ to both sides; the left side already had $-b;$ and $-b+4b=3b;$ you could let me know if you need further explanation; I have no idea why I got a down-vote for this

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. I'm not the one who downvoted you. Could you tell me one last thing? Does the order of operations in this kind of algebra matter? I mean does it matter where I start from and what I do as long as I keep both sides balanced?

Comment: @NiKk:  at any point you could add or subtract something to both sides, or multiply or divide both sides by a non-zero constant, without changing the solution set; and I hope you saw my suggestion in the comments to your question

Comment: Thanks! I would give you an upvote but I can't since I'm new to this stackexchange community (it doesn't let me)...

Comment: That's ok; I appreciate your "acceptance"

Answer (score 0):

In passing from the second line to the third you have an error. You should add $4b$ to the left hand side, not subtract.